# how to open folder of google drive using google drive api in axios/javascript

Tags: javascript, axios, google-api, google-drive-api, fetch-api

I am trying to open the folder and see the files inside

```
const children = await axios.get(
      `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${folder.id}`,
      {
        params: {
          fields: "files(id, name)",
          spaces: "drive",
        },
        headers: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      }
    );
```

can we open sub folder using folder id? i tried it but it show errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As google drive doc uses q parameter to get a list of files inside a folder

```
q:"'{FolderID}' in parents"
```

so your Axios get request will be like that

```
const emptyFoldersSearch2 = await axios.get(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files",
      {
        params: {
          q:"'1VwXsYxTTGid9GIYHzkzD7LPFN5bRUSKD' in parents" ,
        },
        headers: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the q pram [search opperators](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms#operators) with file.list it will let you list the files with in a folder

```
q=parents%20in%20%27root%27
```

Or

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=parents%20in%20%27root%27&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Comment: how can i use it axios with `params: {
          fields: "files(id, name)",
          spaces: "drive",
        },`  i mean what its query will be ?